# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when trying to connect to azure sql server

Tags: sql-server, tcp, sql, microsoft, azure-sql

I'm trying to deploy a SQL database to my azure SQL server. When I'm trying to connect to my target server, I get the error listed below. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server management studio 18 with Windows 10 1909. Any suggestions?

===================================

Cannot connect to quickkartserver1.database.windows.net.

===================================

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10054&LinkId=20476

---

Server Name: quickkartserver1.database.windows.net
Error Number: 10054
Severity: 20
State: 0

---

Program Location:

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacWizard.WizardUtility.VerifyConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType serverType)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of firewall rules are running on your azure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this question. I found a work around by transferring my project to a laptop that can connect to the sql server. Thank you.